# discord.js v12: How do I await for messages in a DM channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, chatbot

This is the code that I've tried:

```js
message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(msg => {
    console.log(msg.content)
});
```

But it returns this error message:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'awaitMessages' of null`

**Updated Code:**

```
message.author.send("What is your name?")

const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id

message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter)
     .then((collected) => console.log(collected.first().content))
```

Comment: If it's saying can't read property of null, then that means your dmChannel doesn't exist. If you look in the docs, `author.dmChannel` has a null propagation operator, which means that it can be null **or** a DMChannel. You probably need to create one first. Although, it would seem that you've already done that with `message.author.send()`. Interesting. Are you sure your `author.send()` line is working properly and that the author receives the message?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `awaitMessages()` properly, you need to pass a `filter`

```js
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id
message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter)
  .then((collected) => console.log(collected.first().content))
```

Comment: I've done this:

`const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id

message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter)
     .then((collected) => console.log(collected.first().content))`

But it still returns the same error message

Answer (score 2):

You should try to create a DM channel first :

```js
let channel = message.author.dmChannel;
if (!channel) channel = await message.author.createDM();
```

Please note that createDM() returns a Promise, which will require you to switch your command to an async function instead (if it already was not)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but before the bot is "awaitingMessages" it is sending a message, doesn't that automatically create the DM channel?

Comment: @Syntle Maybe.. I guess the best way to find out is to try