# TypeError: Cannot read property 'awaitMessages' of null When it is the same as the others

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Code:

```js
if (msg.channel.type == "dm") return; // if dm channel return
let person = msg.author;
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === "!apply") {
  person.send(ally);

  person.dmChannel
    .awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id === person.id, { max: 1, time: 300000 })
    .then((collected) => {
      if (collected.first().toLowerCase() == "yes") {
        // code...
      }
    })
    .catch(person.send(other)); // if dm
} // if !apply
```

I really have no idea what's wrong with this as I was completely fine until I added that bit. Not sure why. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: The error means that `person.dmChannel` is `null`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.js v12: How do I await for messages in a DM channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616893/discord-js-v12-how-do-i-await-for-messages-in-a-dm-channel)

Comment: No, since I am using a filter I think. This what I assume to be exact same code is comes from another bot I have that works perfectly fine.

Comment: My filter is perfectly fine, I changed it to someone else's filter and it had absolutely no difference. Please someone help me I really want this to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `person` as the `message.author.send` function. And then you called the `send()` function on `person`. That's like writing:

```js
functions log(str) {
  return console.log(str);
};

const logger = log;
logger.log(); // logger is a function, and does not have any properties
```

What you should do instead:

```js
// use this one, since you need the entire author object later on
const person = message.author; 
person.send(...);

// although this would theoretically work to (just for the send() function)
const person = message.author.send;
person(...);
```

Circling back, the reason you got the error is that, as mentioned above, the correct function didn't actually trigger. That means a DM was never sent, the `dmChannel` was never opened and thus equals `null`.

Also, since `person` was defined as a function, it doesn't have a `dmChannel` property in the first place.

---

If you're still getting the same error, it might mean that the message has not finished sending before you request the `dmChannel`. There are two ways to combat this.

First of all, you could use [`async/await`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html) to `await` the message's sending, or you could make use of the promise [`Channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=send) returns.

```js
// await method; make sure the message event you're running this in is async
await person.send(ally); 
person.dmChannel
  .awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id === person.id, { max: 1, time: 300000 })

// Promise<message> method
person.send(ally).then((msg) => {
  msg.channel
    .awaitMessages((m) => m.author.id === person.id, { max: 1, time: 300000 })
});
```

Comment: changed person to be
let person = msg.author;
still getting the same error

Comment: Try `await`ing the `person.send()` function

Comment: I don't know how I would await the bot sending something, could you please link a website to help me, or elaborate?

Comment: [Understanding async/await - Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html). What I mean is you change `person.send()` to `await person.send()`